# ${\overline{A}}^{\circ}= \varnothing \Longrightarrow {\overline{A \cap B}}^{\circ}= \varnothing $

Tags: general-topology

If $X$ is a topological space and $A,B,C \subseteq X$ with $B \subseteq A$, I am wondering if the following statements are true.

$(1)$ ${\overline{A}}^{\circ}= \varnothing \Longrightarrow {\overline{B}}^{\circ}= \varnothing$

$(2)$ ${\overline{A}}^{\circ}= \varnothing \Longrightarrow {\overline{A \cap C}}^{\circ}= \varnothing $

I think $(1)$ and $(2)$ are true. I used $\overline{X_1 \cap X_2}^{\circ}\subseteq\overline{X_1 }^{\circ} \cap \overline{ X_2}^{\circ}$ but I am not sure if this is correct.

Comment: Please use the comand \stackrel{\circ}{A} to produce the expression  $\stackrel{\circ}{A}$.

Comment: Is the closure of the interior or the interior of the closure?

Comment: I think the difference is clear: ${\overline{A}}^{\circ}$ and ${\overline{A^{\circ}}}$. This notation is also used in wikipedia:

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_%28topology%29

Comment: I'm sorry, but Wikipedia is not a secure reference, I prefer math books.

Comment: @DiegoMath Probably you agree that the classical Rudin's book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* is a secure reference. Well, he denotes the interior of $E$ by $E^\circ$ (page 43).

Comment: @Pedro Thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The closure of intersection is a subset of intersection of closures](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Closure_of_Intersection_Subset_of_Intersection_of_Closures), that is,
$$\overline{X_1\cap X_2}\subset\overline{X_1}\cap \overline{X_2}$$
[The interior of a subset is a subset of the interior](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Interior_of_Subset). Hence,
$$\overline{X_1\cap X_2}^\circ\subset\left(\overline{X_1}\cap \overline{X_2}\right)^\circ$$
[The interior of a finite intersection equals intersection of interiors](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Interior_of_Finite_Intersection_equals_Intersection_of_Interiors). So,
$$\left(\overline{X_1}\cap \overline{X_2}\right)^\circ=\overline{X_1}^\circ\cap \overline{X_2}^\circ$$
It follows that
$$\overline{X_1\cap X_2}^\circ\subset\overline{X_1}^\circ\cap \overline{X_2}^\circ$$
and thus your solution is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You know $B\subseteq A$. In particular $\overline B\subseteq\overline A$. If $\overline B$ contains an open set, so does $\overline A$, hence $(1)$ is proven. The second follows from the first, since $A\cap C\subseteq A$.

Comment: I am sorry, I corrected $C$.

Comment: War of the Pedros... :-P

Comment: @AsafKaragila I shot first. I did! Also, I think I got what I was asking yesterday. On the other hand, I feel like Enderton's book treats me like a toddler! =D

Comment: You are. Are you not?

Comment: @AsafKaragila *pouts* Set theoretically? Maybe.

Comment: That too. Kid. :-)